# link error: undefined reference to

Tags: c++, g++

when I try to link them together, I got this error. what's wrong? Do I need to put `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` in the header file and both cpp files? is there a way that I only need to include `<iostream>` and `using namespace std;` once? Thanks in advance.

Error:

```
/tmp/cczgScpr.o: In function `main':
time_overloaded_operators.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `Time::Time(unsigned int const&, unsigned int const&, unsigned int const&, unsigned int const&)'
time_overloaded_operators.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `operator*(Time const&, int const&)'
time_overloaded_operators.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Time const&)'
time_overloaded_operators.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Time const&)'
time_overloaded_operators.cpp:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to `Time::~Time()'
time_overloaded_operators.cpp:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `Time::~Time()'
time_overloaded_operators.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `Time::~Time()'
time_overloaded_operators.cpp:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `Time::~Time()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main cpp:

```
// practice on overloading operators on Time variables
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"
using namespace std;
//main function
int main() {
  Time time1(0,1,0,0);
  Time time3 = time1 * 2;
  cout << time1 << endl;
  cout << time3 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

header file:

```
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Time {
 public:
  //constructor
  Time(const unsigned int& day, const unsigned int& hour,
       const unsigned int& minute, const unsigned int& second);
  //copy constructor
  Time(const Time& time);
  //assignment operator
  Time& operator=(const Time& time); 
  //destructor
  ~Time(); 
  //member functions
  //overloaded operators
  Time& operator+=(const Time& time); 
  Time operator+(const Time& time);
  friend Time operator*(const Time& time, const int& integer_number);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Time& time);
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Time& time);
  friend bool operator==(const Time& first_object, const Time& second_object);
  friend bool operator!=(const Time& first_object, const Time& second_object);

 private:
  unsigned int day_;
  unsigned int hour_;
  unsigned int minute_;
  unsigned int second_;
  void ConvertSecondsToTime();
  unsigned int TotalTimeInSeconds() const;
};
#endif
```

implementation file:

```
#include "Time.h"
#include <iostream>
// class constructors
Time::Time(const unsigned int& day = 0, const unsigned int& hour = 0,
       const unsigned int& minute = 0, const unsigned int& second = 0)
    : day_(day),
      hour_(hour),
      minute_(minute),
      second_(second) {
}

Time::Time(const Time& time)
    : day_(time.day_),
      hour_(time.hour_),
      minute_(time.minute_),
      second_(time.second_) {
}
Time& Time::operator=(const Time& time) {
    day_ = time.day_;
    hour_ = time.hour_;
    minute_ = time.minute_;
    second_ = time.second_;
    return *this;
}
Time::~Time() {}
  //overloaded operators
unsigned int Time::TotalTimeInSeconds() const {
  return (day_ * 24 * 60 * 60 
          + hour_ * 60 * 60 
          + minute_ * 60 
          + second_);
}
void Time::ConvertSecondsToTime() {
  while (second_ >= 60) {
    second_ -= 60;
    minute_ += 1;
  }
  while (minute_ >= 60) {
    minute_ -= 60;
    hour_ += 1;
  } 
  while (hour_ >= 24) {
    hour_ -= 24;
    day_ += 1;
  }
}
T    ime& Time::operator+=(const Time& time) {
  Time temp;
  temp.second_ = TotalTimeInSeconds() + time.TotalTimeInSeconds();
  *this = temp;
  ConvertSecondsToTime();
  return *this;
}
Time Time::operator+(const Time& time) {
  Time temp(*this);
  temp += time;
  return temp;
}
Time operator*(const Time& time, const int& integer_number) {
  Time temp;
  temp.second_ = time.TotalTimeInSeconds() * integer_number;
  temp.ConvertSecondsToTime();
  return temp;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Time& time) {
  output << "days: " << time.day_ 
         << " hours: " << time.hour_ 
         << " minutes: " << time.minute_
         << " seconds: " << time.second_ << endl;
  return output;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Time& time) {
  input >> time.day_ >> time.hour_ >> time.minute_ >> time.second_;
  if (!input) {
    time = Time();
  }
  return input;
}
bool operator==(const Time& first_object, const Time& second_object) {
  return first_object.TotalTimeInSeconds()
         == second_object.TotalTimeInSeconds();
}
bool operator!=(const Time& first_object, const Time& second_object) {
  return !(first_object == second_object);
}
```

Comment: **Never** put `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Comment: What's your command line? Ie, what is the full line of g++ that you're using to build this?

Comment: The error messages say that the methods in the class `Time` can't be found. We need to see how you build your project (i.e. the command line), most importantly how you call the linker.

Comment: I put `g++ -Wall -o time main.cpp`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth if I erase `using namespace std`I got `Time.h:20: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘ostream’ with no type` How would you write this header file? and where would you put `using namespace std` Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
g++ main.cpp time.cpp
```

should fix your link error so that main can link to time functions. If the **Time** member functions are implemented in a shared library you will have to pass that to [linker](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html). Typically like `-llibraryname`